# Impedir que usuario digite numeros e simbolos. Porem problema algo usar Botoes CapsLock

Tags: javascript, formulário, input, validação

Quando clico no input e  aperto Caps Lock, Backspace, ele manda a mensagem de correçao do preenchimento.
por exemplo, eu digito o input normal e seguro backspace pra apagar tudo, quando chega no final ele mostra a mensagem de "preencha apenas com letras". Utilizei este codigo (name.match(/^[a-z" "A-Z_]+$/) porem gostaria de liberar CapsLock e Backspace.

```
//Reservation validation
const nameinput = document.getElementsByClassName('names');  
const emailinput = document.querySelector('input[name="email"]');  
const submitinput = document.querySelector('input[name="submitreservation"]');  
console.log(nameinput);  
Array.from(nameinput).forEach(function (item) {
item.addEventListener('keyup', function (e) {
var name = e.target.value;

    if (name.match(/^[a-z" "A-Z_]+$/)) {
        e.target.value = name.toUpperCase();
    }
    else {
        console.log(e.target.value)
        alert('Digite apenas letras !');
        e.target.value ="";
    }

})
})
```

Comment: Não entendi muito bem, você gostaria que não aparecesse a mensagem do CapsLock e Backspace?

Comment: Isso Alvaro. Quano clico no input e aperto backspace se estiver vazio, msm coisa com Caps aparece o erro. nao quero isto. apenas com numeros e simbolos

Comment: o amigo fechou o post, mas nao tem nada haver com a minha pergunta

Comment: eu sinalizei as moderadores pq sua pergunta nao 'e duplicada e sobre validacao com regex